# How to add an embedded thumbnail to a video file with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I'm encoding some videos and I'd like to add a thumbnail which would load faster than the filesystem browser auto-generating it with the default approach. I've found a number of separate tools which either generate or add existing thumbnails, but I'd like an ffmpeg solution since I'm using it for encoding already. The thumbnail should be an image from either 25% or 33% of the video's duration.

Answer (score 3):

First use ffprobe to get encoded file's duration,

```
DURATION=$(ffprobe -show_entries format=duration -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 file.mp4)
```

and the quarter point

```
DUR=$(echo "$DURATION/4" | bc)
```

Extract and attach thumbnail,

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -ss $DUR -i file.mp4 -map 1:v:0 -map 0 -filter:v:0 scale=320:-1,trim=end_frame=1 -c copy -c:v:0 mjpeg -disposition:0 attached_pic out.mp4
```

Comment: This swears at me about "attached_pic" ... where does that come from?

Comment: ffmpeg doesn't ever swear. Upgrade ffmpeg - that value was added sometime within the last year.